# Am i supposed to add all page level js to assets.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement simple HTML template to Rails app. 
There are many JS files used in.

I converted all JS references to Rails `javascript_include_tag` and it's always asking me to add them to the `assets.rb` file. It's extremely time consuming.

My `assets.rb` file is looking like:

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['ea/*'] 
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap/* )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css
)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( css/* )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/js/bootstrap-extension.min.js
)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  js/jquery.slimscroll.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/peity/jquery.peity.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/peity/jquery.peity.init.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( js/waves.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( js/custom.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( js/dashboard1.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
  plugins/bower_components/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js )
```

Is there any easy solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually all or most of js are packed into a single js bundle (see [guide on asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)) and you will have single `javascript_include_tag('application')` and `application.js` manifest like:

```
  //= require_directory ./ea
  //= require_tree bootstrap
  //= require jquery/dist/jquery.min
  //= require bootstrap-extension/js/bootstrap-extension.min
  //= require sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min
  //= require js/jquery.slimscroll
  //= require raphael/raphael-min
  //= require morrisjs/morris
  //= require jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min
  //= require peity/jquery.peity.min
  //= require peity/jquery.peity.init
  //= require js/waves
  //= require js/custom.min
  //= require js/dashboard1
  //= require styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js
```

and similar for css

Comment: Thanks for info.I think this is a better practice but i understand that i should add all folders and subfolders anyways.It's not enough to add only main folder right?

Comment: `require_directory` adds all files from folder, `require_tree` also adds from subfolders. Also files can have their own `require`s